# Will deleting an object set its references equal to NULL?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I have an array of pointers to pointers, and when I do `array [index]=classpointer;` and call `delete classpointer;`, will the value stored at `array[index]` become NULL?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but your question title is about whether the *array as a whole* will equal NULL, your question itself asks about whether the *index variable* becomes NULL, and the only reasonable interpretation of your question is that you're actually asking about whether a *particular array member* becomes NULL. You need to be a lot more precise before you can even think about using pointers!

Comment: To add to what Tom said, that the value of classpointer is stored in an array is essentially irrelevant to your question.  It could be saved in any other variable and you would have the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

No. It still remains pointing to the location `classpointer` was earlier pointing to or in other words, it goes dangling.

Comment: @RandenDavis : The pointer value will be the same as it was pre-`delete`, but dereferencing that pointer will invoke [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Randen Davis - No. Once you do `delete classpointer;`, `classpointer` pointing resources get deallocated. So, pointer at `array[index]` goes dangling and dereferencing it leads to **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 4):

No. An array index is always an integer (unless you're doing some crazy operator overloading). Integers are primitive datatypes and it doesn't make sense for a primitive to be NULL.

Did you mean, "Will array[index] become NULL?" See @Mahesh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To help you remember the answer to this, consider:

```
T* p = ...;
delete p;
```

What happens to `p` afterward the `delete` and before it itself leaves scope, or the object it's member data for is destroyed?  There is no single answer.  So, if C++ took the additional action to set `p` to `NULL`, then at least some of the time it would wasted effort - setting a variable that was discarded immediately afterwards.  In C++, a guiding principle is that there aren't runtime costs for features you may not want or need.

Further, consider:

```
T* p = ...
T* p1 = p;
delete p;
```

Suddenly the idea of having `p` set to `NULL` - which may have seemed to make it easy to check pointers for validity - falls over.  It's just not practical for the compiler to know every other pointer that might still refer to the just-deleted object, and the cost of tracking that information at run-time and NULLing all the pointers is impractical.

So, to be really explicit, if in...

```
T* p = ...;
delete p;
```

...`p` was set to 0x12345678, then after the `delete` `p` will still be 0x12345678.  `delete` never changes its argument.  Any attempt to access the memory at that address will result in undefined behaviour (unless of course the same address happens to be returned by a subsequent heap allocation request).

Separately, if you do set a pointer to `NULL` yourself, you can safely call `delete` on it again, so there's never any point in doing this:

```
if (p != NULL) delete p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if it's a `std::weak_ptr`.  Normal pointers will remain unchanged.